# Combine select rows into 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sorry, I know others have asked similar questions to this but I read those answers and still couldn't figure this out.

I need to make

```
Whatever    StudentID   SchoolID    Types    
qw          1           A           c    
we          2           B           a    
we          2           B           r    
ty          3           C           f    
ty          3           C           t    
yu          4           D           k
```

into

```
Whatever    StudentID   SchoolID    Types    
qw          1           A           c    
we          2           B           ar    -- concat
ty          3           C           ft    -- concat
yu          4           D           k
```

Thanks for your help. I tried using xml paths but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @hich database are you using? (from xmlpaths I am guessing sql server)

Comment: Yes, sql server. And Transact-SQL if that matters.